# APNS for Inhouse Apps - Sandbox only?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, sandbox, mdm, in-house-distribution

Our app is being distributed via MDM (AirWatch in this case) as an InHouse app.

We can send APNS messages to the app and all works find, but only when we use the APNS sandbox.

When we use the production APNS server at Apple and the production certificate, Apple rejects the message.

Do InHouse apps distributed with MDM not work with production APN servers at Apple?

The Error we get is, "Apple Error code : Invalid token" when the production APNS server is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your device that you use for test is not bind with server's token or bound with some errors. I'm not sure but it can be an error in your server logic or invalid certificate used. Rather it is a problem with certificates. What kind of provider you use on your server?

Comment: I had a similar problem and i found solution in "Certificates" section in [this](http://blog.serverdensity.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/) document.

Comment: I'm using the Moons APNS open source project to send the messages via a Windows .NET console app. The certs are exported from Keychain as p12s. I'll redo all the certs and see if that's the issue.

Comment: I dont think the problem is with the tokens bound, how can apple send the push notification to the device without receiving the app. Inhouse apps are not submitted to app store.